# Android TextView with Dynamic Links

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview

I have an Android TextView which needs to show both types of links:

- > http://google.com
- `<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>`

My code is as follows:

```
txtView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
txtView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p><a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Google</a></p><p>http://google.com is also a link</p>"));
```

If I use:

```
android:autoLink="web|email|phone"
android:linksClickable="true"
```

then the links are stripped and if I exclude only the first link is shown. Any ideas how to solve? Note: I cannot know in advance which html I get as it is provided by the user. I also need to be able to linkify phone numbers, email address.

Comment: You can write method onclick of textview.. which will open url in webview

Comment: Can you clarify? The textview will show both at the same time? or one at a time?

Comment: You can achieve this by using `Spannable String`

Comment: [http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring)